# Static service not working when using SCAN?

Tags: oracle

I know the correctly way to configure service is creating a resource in with `srvctl add service` command, but I've seen a behavior after configure a static listener in a RAC environment. It's not possible to connect in the static service using the `SCAN`, just with the `vip/public` IP. This behavior is correctly? or probably a bad configuration in my environment?

Usually a just configure a static listener in a `RAC` when using data guard broker, which broker uses the vip.

Comment: What do you mean by "static listener"? A hardcoded service in listener.ora? I believe the SCAN listeners require everything to be defined using srvctl.

Comment: Yes, a service created inside of listener.ora. I guess as well.. I've made some tests and not work with scan. But it's just a doubt about.

Comment: why don't you use the local listener to define the static entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static registration is no longer required starting with 12.1.0.2, as the DG broker uses Grid Infrastructure to restart instances. Of course, if you have a single instance database without Grid Infrastructure, there it is still required.

[Oracle Data Guard Broker and Static Service Registration (Doc ID 1387859.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1387859.1)

Also in the above document:

> From 11.2 on, never register the entries with the SCAN listener as it
> is not associated with a specific host.

I have never seen anyone using static registration in SCAN listeners, so I had to try this myself. On a 2-node cluster with 3 SCAN listeners, I added the below to `listener.ora`, first node:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN1,SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN2,SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN3=
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = TEST_SERVICE)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = TEST1)
  )
 )
```

Second node:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN1,SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN2,SID_LIST_LISTENER_SCAN3=
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = TEST_SERVICE)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = TEST2)
  )
 )
```

Yes, it worked, but I would still not do it because of the above reasons.