How to register static listener in listener_scan as well?
I have a listener called "monitoramento" which has three static listener.
SID_LIST_MONITORAMENTO=
   (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC=
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME=BRXXX_MONITORAMENTO)
         (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
         (SID_NAME=BRXXX))
      (SID_DESC=
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=FAXXX_MONITORAMENTO)
          (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
          (SID_NAME=FAXXX))
      (SID_DESC=
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=FUXXX_MONITORAMENTO)
          (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
          (SID_NAME=FUXXX))
    )

It is showed in monitoramento listener.
Service "BRXX_MONITORAMENTO" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "BRXXX", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "FAXXX_MONITORAMENTO" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "FAXXX", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "FUXXX_MONITORAMENTO" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "FUXXX", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

But it is not showed in LISTENER_SCAN1,LISTENER_SCAN2 and LISTENER_SCAN3. I can't connect to BRXX_MONITORAMENTO, FAXXX_MONITORAMENTO and FUXXX_MONITORAMENTO through scan, only directly using the local listener. How to register static listener to scan as well?
I mean, I cannot connect as
sqlplus xxxxxx/xxxx@xxxx-scan:1521/BRXXX_MONITORAMENTO

only as
sqlplus xxxxxx/xxxx@local_listener-ip:1522/BRXXX_MONITORAMENTO


https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/276948/static-service-not-working-when-using-scan

@BalazsPapp but in that case, if I need to stop connections through BRXX_MONITORAMENTO service, will need to stop the entire scan listener (which afect other services).

No, you can reload a listener.

Let's say I have only a scan and all application connect through it (with other services names), but I need to stop only connections through  BRXX_MONITORAMENTO, I would need to stop the scan (and all applications went down).

No, the listener is responsible for establishing new connections. Existing sessions are not affected by such an action.

This should do
SQL>alter system set remote_listener = 'xxx-scan:1521' sid='*';

Best of luck!
